# how to display string with string count

Tags: java, collections

I am having string array like this:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"foo","bar","foo","car"}
```

I need output like this:

```
bar1car1foo2
```

I tried like this:

```
String[] someArray = new String[] { "foo","bar","foo","car"};

            for(int i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
                int count=0;
                for(int j=0;j<someArray.length;j++){
                    if(someArray[i].equals(someArray[j])){

                        someArray[i] +=count;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(someArray[i]);
                }
```

and my output is:

```
foo0
bar0
foo0
car0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just for the record: Andreas is actually correct - you didn't show any signs on solving the problem on your own. So you have been very lucky that some folks were in the mood of answering nonetheless; but don't let yourself being fooled into the believe that SO is a site where you should just drop your requirements and other people do the work for you. Be assured: most of the time that ends in very negative feedback for you.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `Map<String, Integer>` where the keys represent the individual strings, and the map value is the counter for each one.

So you can do something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> stringsWithCount = new TreeMap<>();
for (String item : str) {
  if (stringsWithCount.contains(item)) {
    stringsWithCount.put(item, stringsWithCount.get(item)+1));
  } else {
    stringsWithCount.put(item, 0);
  }
}
```

And then you can iterate the map when done:

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stringsWithCount.entrySet()) {
```

and build your result string.

That was like the old-school implementation; if you want to be fancy and surprise your teachers, you can go for the Java8/lambda/stream solution:

```
Arrays.stream(str)
  .collect(Collectors
     .groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), String.valueOf(e.getValue())))
  .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

But of course, you should be able to explain that piece of code.

Comment: Or this: `Arrays.stream(str).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining())`

Comment: Can also replace `map(e -> e.getKey() + e.getValue())` with `flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), String.valueOf(e.getValue())))`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much; added that to my questions.

Comment: Note the use of `TreeMap` to ensure the values are returned in alphabetical order, which is *implied* by the "need output" example in the question.

Comment: You can replace s -> s with Function.identity()

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] strArray = new String[] { "foo","bar","foo","car"};
        countduplicate(strArray );
        }


public static void countduplicate(String avalue[]) {
    String str = "";
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < avalue.length; i++) {
        set.add(avalue[i]);
    }
    Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int count=0;
        str =iterator.next(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < avalue.length; i++) {
            if(str.equals(avalue[i])){
                count++;
            }
        }
            list.add(str+count);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: **Very** inefficient way to do it. Also, why no use of the simpler [enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class StringCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = new String[]{"foo","bar","foo","car","foo","car","bar","bar"};
    Set<String> set= new TreeSet<String>();
    for(String a : str){
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(a.equals(str[i])){
                c=c+1;
            }
        }
        set.add(a+c);
    }
    System.out.println(set);
}

}


TreeSet is used to get the sorted elements.
Output:
[bar3, car2, foo3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```java
public static void countAndPrint(String[] elements) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String item: elements) {
        int occurrences = map.containsKey(item)? map.get(item) + 1: 1;
        map.put(item, occurrences);
    }
    for(String item: map.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(item);
        System.out.print(map.get(item));
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] elements = new String[]{"foo","bar","foo","car"};
    countAndPrint(elements);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SortedBag` from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) to solve this problem.

```
String[] str = {"foo","bar","foo","car"};
Bag<String> bag = SortedBags.mutable.with(str);
bag.forEachWithOccurrences(((each, occurrences) -> System.out.print(each + occurrences)));
```

Outputs: `bar1car1foo2`

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.